# PHP file doesn't write to current directory?

Tags: php, apache, web, web-hosting

I have a PHP file on a web-host that is as follows:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('test.txt','TEST');    
echo 'OK';

?>
```

But the file `test.txt` is not created when I execute the page from a browser.  Why not?  Is it a permissions issue?

Comment: It's certainly a permission issue.

Answer (score 4):

yes the PHP Doc Says

> If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

That is only if you write have permission on that folder .... try

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");

if (! is_writable(__DIR__)) {
    trigger_error("I don't have permission");
}

file_put_contents('test.txt', 'TEST');
```

Comment: How do I give the apache process permission to write to that folder?

Comment: You have to change the owner of the current folder or the permissions of the folder.

Comment: That is very easy .. i dot advice you to do that on your default directory ... create a directory called `data` use your ftp client to change the permission setting to 0777 or use `chmod("/somedir", 755);` ..if you are not the owner it would not work so use the ftp option instead

Comment: Do you mean 777 or 755?  755 would not give write permission to the folder.

Comment: After setting a sub-directory to 0777, I've noticed that a file was created by user `apache` of group `apache`.  Is there a way I can give permission to only the `apache` user or group rather than to everyone?

Comment: The most important thing is that you can write to that folder .... try your php script again and point to the folder

Comment: @Baba: I have got it working by using 0777, but is there a way to do it without global write access to the folder?

Comment: Already told you have global right to a specific folder .... not root folder ... if you admin permission you can change owner just the way you created the folder

Comment: I have created a specific folder and made it global writable, but can I give only the `apache` user write access?

Answer (score 1):

> Why not? Is it a permissions issue?

The question you should be asking yourself is why don't you know already?

The code will be producing an error or warning - why don't you know what that is?

It's likely a permissions issue - what are the permissions?

BTWE: writing content within your document root, to a directory which will execute PHP is a huge security vulnerability. i.e. if it is a permissions issue, then changing the permissions is the *wrong* way to solve the problem.