# PHP file doesn't write to current directory?

Tags: web-hosting, php, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP file doesn’t write to current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008850/php-file-doesnt-write-to-current-directory)

I have a PHP file on a web-host that is as follows:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('test.txt','TEST');    
echo 'OK';

?>
```

But the file `test.txt` is not created when I execute the page from a browser.  Why not?  Is it a permissions issue?

Comment: Do you have any errors? `file_put_contents` returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure. Try to see what `file_put_contents` returns.

Comment: Do you have all permission in your location where you save file ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a permission error in the folder. You will need to ensure that the folder as write permission for the user that PHP runs as.

Answer (score 0):

what i have seen in such situation, you always had permission problems. Play with 777, 770 ,760.You will solve your problem yourself.

Comment: It only works with 777.  How could I go to 755?